# What is the tsconfig equivalent for the cli parameter --generateTrace?

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig, compiler-options, angular-compiler

If you run `tsc` manually and use the param:

```sh
tsc --generateTrace traceDir
```

you can create a new `traceDir` directory with paired trace and types files. A recent analysis package from Microsoft [typescript-analyze-trace](https://github.com/microsoft/typescript-analyze-trace) can analyse those files.

**Questions:**

I wanted to configure `generateTrace`  within `tsconfig.json` and couldn't find the equivalent property.

Is there a similar configuration option also in an angular app? I guess I can use the same property within `angularCompilerOptions` (if I knew what it is called)?

Comment: Are you trying to get the same file outputs, just automatically during a build process?

Comment: I'm sure you've already see this https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html
generateTrace is a flag, not an option so it wouldn't have a parallel in the tsconfig file. 
What you could try doing is adding this command to one of your script shorthands, ie npm buildWithTrace : npm build projectName && tsc --generateTrace

Comment: yes, I know that, thank you, maybe it will then come soon as a tsconfig.json property, let’s see,I wanted to be sure,..

Comment: yep, maybe soon. best of luck!

Comment: give your answer, say, it is not possible yet and get the bounty ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you've already seen this

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

generateTrace is a flag, not an option so it wouldn't have a parallel in the tsconfig file.

What you could try doing is adding this command to one of your script shorthands, ie npm buildWithTrace : npm build projectName && tsc --generateTrace

But otherwise, this doesn't seem to be possible yet.